# Django render_to_string not working inside update of djangoRestFramework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, functools

I try to use the `render_to_string` method of django to generate a html. This function is actually called inside a signal which is sent inside the `update` method of a djangoRestFramework serializer.
By doing that I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I tried to debug and what I see is that the `render_to_string` method does not work inside the `update` block of the serializer.
As I use a generic from rest_framework `UpdateAPIView` I did not manage to put break points inside the view. But before calling the url and the view the `render_to_string` works well.
I tried to find the error from the django source code but couldn't find where it comes from.

Here is the part of the code where I call the render_to_string function:

```
class AnalysisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        t = render_to_string('template/order.html')
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are calling the `render_to_string`.

Comment: I shared the part of the code that I put to test in the serializer

Comment: can you please share your error traceback too? As its seems like the problem isn't with the `render_to_string` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have properly configured template path in TEMPLATE config in `settings.py`

Comment: yes I have because before entering the serializer it works well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood why. The error was not caused by the render_to_string method but by the tests. I was actually having this issue by using it inside a pytest process. The function causing this error is

```
django/test/utils.py:100: in instrumented_test_render
    template_rendered.send(sender=self, template=self, context=context)
```

Which is called during testing. Mocking this function in the test of the url and testing the signal itself on another test solved the issue.